# Could not parse the remainder: '[0]' from 'item[0]' Django

Tags: python, html, arrays, django, list

I am trying to make a table with values I get from a list but I keep getting the error "Could not parse the remainder: '[0]' from 'item[0]'" whenever I try to access an item in a list inside the main list.

The part of the code that is giving me problems is:

```
{% for item in lista_completa %}
<tr>
    <td>
        {{ item[0] }}
    </td>
    <td>
        {{ item[1] }}
    </td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

And the list is something like this:

```
lista_completa = [[1,'a'],[1,'b'],[3,'c']]
```

I tried using {% item[0] %} instead but I got the same error.

Thanks

Answer (score 78):

You would write the following to get item `0`:

```
 {{ item.0 }}
```

Similarly, to get the first item of the first item you'd write:

```
{{ item.0.0 }}
```

Comment: in my case it was a dict so i wanted a tag value from `foo = {"id" : 33, "tag": "games"}` this what it works `foo.0.tag` note that 0 is first list in queryset

Comment: How about `x[-1]` ?